# Installing Laravel 4.2 via Laravel installer not possible on windows?

Tags: php, windows, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

While installing laravel on windows via laravel installer with command `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"` then `laravel new project-name` , it now instal laravel 5.0, latest version. How to install laravel 4.2 version via laravel installer with `laravel new` command??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No that's not possible with the laravel installer. It will always get the latest release. Here's the [source of the `laravel new` command](https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php#L80)

```
protected function download($zipFile)
{
    $response = \GuzzleHttp\get('http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip')->getBody();
    //                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
    file_put_contents($zipFile, $response);
    return $this;
}
```

---

What you can do is use `composer create-project` and specify the version:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name ~4.2.0 --prefer-dist
```

By the way `~4.2.0` means that you will get the latest version with `4.2.*` (currently that's 4.2.11)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on top of homestead:

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel YOURFOLDERNAME 4.2.*
```

Note the * for the version #.

Outputs:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.2.11)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v4.2.11)
    Downloading: 100%
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan to create multiple 4.2 projects, you can install single one by issuing another Composer command:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel foldername "4.2" --prefer-dist`

where foldername is a name of folder for your project and "4.2" specifies version to install.

I tried it on my Windows 7 machine just now, it works.

P.S. Laravel documentation shows slightly different syntax:
`composer create-project laravel/laravel "4.2" --prefer-dist`
but this creates 5.0 installation in folder named "4.2".

Comment: Yes, I tried composer create-project laravel/laravel "4.2" --prefer-dist as given in Laravel Doc. It doesn't work. I'll try with foldername wtih ~4.2

Comment: @Surah Remember to replace 'foldername' with folder name of your choice/preference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete XAMMP and/or Homestead
2. Install Laragon (http://laragon.org/)

This should solve the problem. Happy Programming

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {{projectName}} 4.2.* --prefer-dist
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Download [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

and run

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel [name] 4.2.* --prefer-dist
```

where [name] is your projects name.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use composer

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist
```

Just open your power shell and cd to the directory you want to run the project, and run the above command, make sure you have [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) first.